Robotic Process Automation on iOS device, some operations are not supported by Shortcuts
The iPhone is unlocked, and developer mode is enable, so that I'd like to do some complex and repetitive operations that are not supported by Shortcuts, Is it possible to do these things by swift code?
I have tried appium, but it fails; thanks!
